# How to escape `$` and `#` symbols in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a simple string I want to echo from my bash script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#cf-footer-paragraph').append('<p>Revision 12345</p>');});
```

But any how I try to add `\` before # I cant echo it=( So I wonder - how to echo such command?

Comment: tried using double quotes " instead of single ' ?......of course you will still need to escape any $, ' and \ .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because you already have single quotes in the string, use double quotes, and escape only the `$` sign:

```
echo "\$(document).ready(function() {\$('#cf-footer-paragraph').append('<p>Revision 12345</p>');});"
```